# Downloading .xlsx file returning corrupt file

Tags: c#, excel

I have made the following button in C#, and it is returning a corrupt .xlsx file when the button is selected in the interface. The original file itself has no issues whatsoever.

```
protected void download_Data(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string strFullPath = Server.MapPath("~/Content/Demo User data file.xlsx");
    string strContents = null;
    System.IO.StreamReader objReader = default(System.IO.StreamReader);
    objReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(strFullPath);
    strContents = objReader.ReadToEnd();
    objReader.Close();

    string attachment = "attachment; filename=Demo User data file.xlsx";
    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment);
    Response.Write(strContents);
    Response.End();
}
```

Comment: Why not simply call [`Response.WriteFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.writefile) on the mapped file path?

Comment: The double /application is a mistake. After adjusting it to: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet I still get the same corrupt excel file.

Comment: What do you mean by call Response.Writefile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=myfile.xlsx");
Response.BinaryWrite(File.ReadAllBytes(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Demo User data file.xlsx")));
Response.End();
```

Comment: what's the issue?

Comment: I replaced "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"; with "application/vnd.ms-excel". This did not help..

Comment: Do i have to specify something for file?

Comment: you have to add " using System.IO; "

Comment: Thanks!! That was very helpful.

Comment: Glad it helped.!

Answer (score 1):

This works

```
      protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

            string strFullPath = Server.MapPath("~/Content/Sample Contact.xlsx");




        string attachment = "attachment; filename=Sample_Contact.xlsx";
        Response.ClearContent();
       Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment);
        Response.BinaryWrite(File.ReadAllBytes(strFullPath));

        Response.End();
    }
```

Comment: this works for me as well: ContentType: `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet`

Answer (score 0):

Try Flushing and Closing the HttpResponse request.

```
response.OutputStream.Flush();
response.OutputStream.Close();
response.Flush();
response.Close();
```